# Use PDFLib to search through PDF's with PHP

Tags: php, search, pdf, pdflib

I'm about to rent my own server and for one of my projects I need to be able to search through PDF files. I've asked the hosting provider to install xPDF but they replied they want to install PDFLib instead. My question, am I able to open and search through PDF files with PDFLib? I'm Googling as a madman but I can't seem to find much about searching PDF's, I'm only finding information about generating PDF's.

Can someone please provide me with an answer, and even better, resources where to find the specified information?

Comment: AFAIK, basic PDFLib is write-only.  maybe you should get a cheap VPS so you can install whatever you want (I've heard great things of linode.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xPDF was later installed, and i got rid of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've used PDFLib on some projects but only the core PDFLib+PDI. They also have a Text Extraction Toolkit, specifically for search.

[PDFLib TET](http://www.pdflib.com/products/tet-pdf-ifilter/)

pdftk has some metadata extraction and object stream decompression.

[pdftk](http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/index.html#examples)